# jqgrid subgrid shows old data even when rowdata is updated

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have implemented **jqgrid** with subgrid for my data. I have custom implemented functionality of edit row and save new data and on save data I also update new data to my database. After saving successfully I used `"setRowData"` function to set new data on row. It works, but when I close **subgrid** and expand again then grid shows old data.
can anyone give me solution

My code is

```
 $.ajax({
        url: DomainName + "Report/UpdateClockInOutTime",
        type: "get",
        data: { ClockId: ClockId, ClockInTime: ClockInTime, ClockOutTime: ClockOutTime },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == "True") {        
                var rowId = nRow.attr('id');
                var rowData = $("#" + TableId).jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
                rowData.Working_Hr = diff;
                rowData.ClockIn = ClockInTime;
                rowData.ClockOut = ClockOutTime;
                rowData.edit = '<a href="#modal-3" id="hrfEditClockInOut_timestamp" class="btn" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>';

               $("#" + TableId).jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, rowData);                                              
            }
            else {
                alert("Time not updated")
            }

        }
    })
```

Comment: You don't posted any code which shows how you create jqGrid and subgrid. The code which you post gives almost no information which could help to solve your main problem. Moreover it's absolutely unclear for me why you don't use standard editing features of jqGrid like inline editing or form editing. It will automatically send the changes to the server (to `editurl` parameter of jqGrid) and update the local data. You don't need to make any separate Ajax request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh jqGrid using -

```
("#" + TableId).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: i already do this. but does not work when again expand subgrid

Comment: If you are using subgrid you may not be taking the correct id, try this -

Comment: var thegrid = $("#" + subGridID + "_t").

Comment: i am getting proper id of subgrid. for this i do

Comment: var nRow = $(this).closest("td").closest("tr");
    var TableId = nRow.closest('table').attr('id');

Comment: in alert i get "tblEmployeeReport_1_t"